# error when using conda env upload

Tags: anaconda, conda

I recently reinstalled Anaconda and I'm currently unable to upload an environment to Anaconda cloud account, getting the following error:

```
$ conda env upload --file c:/users/mweber/temp/StreamCat.yml
```

Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Uploading environment StreamCat to anaconda-server (https://api.anaconda.org)...
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

```
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues
```

Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.21
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : 1.20.0
     python version : 2.7.13.final.0
   requests version : 2.13.0
   root environment : f:\Continuum\Anaconda2  (writable)
default environment : f:\Continuum\Anaconda2
   envs directories : f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs
                      C:\Users\mweber\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      c:\Users\mweber\.conda\envs
      package cache : f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\pkgs
                      C:\Users\mweber\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : c:\Users\mweber\.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.13.0 CPython/2.7.13 Windows/7 Windows/6.1.7601
      administrator : False
```

`$ f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-env-script.py upload --file c:/users/mweber/temp/StreamCat.yml`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 632, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_upload.py", line 101, in execute
    info = uploader.upload()
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda_env\utils\uploader.py", line 81, in upload
    if self.is_ready():
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda_env\utils\uploader.py", line 94, in is_ready
    return self.ensure_package_namespace() and self.ensure_distribution()
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda_env\utils\uploader.py", line 109, in ensure_package_namespace
    self.binstar.add_release(self.username, self.packagename, self.version, {}, '', '')
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 417, in add_release
    self._check_response(res)
  File "f:\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 216, in _check_response
    raise ErrCls(msg, res.status_code)
BinstarError: (u'Bad Request: Bad request syntax or unsupported method ([POST] https://api.anaconda.org/release/mweber36/StreamCat/2017.06.21.1612 -> 400)', 400)
```

I'm able to upload the exact environment .yml file from another user's machine, but I get this error on both win-64 and ubuntu-64 platforms with similiar conda install as shown above.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated - posted issue to conda GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: If you recently reinstalled, did you update all your packages, particularly the `anaconda-client` package? Also, can you post a link to the GitHub issue?

Comment: @darthbith, thanks, I did try updating `anaconda-client` package, `4.3.21-py27_1 conda-forge --> 4.3.22-py27_0 conda-forge`, but same error - as far as i can tell my packages are the same version as  the machine I was able to upload on to Anaconda cloud.  [GitHub issue link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5567)